# Basic factoring problem.

Tags: factoring

I trying to work through a problem and have become stuck at the following equality:

$ \sum_{n=1}^{100}{ n^2+n - 1 - (n-1)^2} = \sum_{n=1}^{100}{(3n - 2)}$

I can't quite get my head around the factoring.
Could anybody help out? Many thanks!

Comment: $(n-1)^2=n^2-2n+1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't factoring, it is unfactoring (expanding). We have $(n-1)^2=n^2-2n+1$ and therefore 
$$(n^2+n-1)-(n-1)^2=(n^2+n-1)-(n^2-2n+1)=3n-2.$$

Answer (score 1):

Since:
$$(n-1)^2=n^2-2n+1$$
Then:
$$n^2+n-1-(n-1)^2=n^2+n-1-(n^2-2n+1)=3n-2$$